# How to INVISIBLE button from recylerview permenantly?Android studio with java

Tags: button, android-recyclerview, download, show-hide, function-binding

i have 114 items in recylerview , each item have Download button, i want when user click on download then it start downloading and after downloading button shoud be INVISIBLE, i am using button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLLE) ,but when i close app and reopen app then again all button are visible.

Comment: Can you show what you have done already in code? maybe showing adapter of your recyclerview.

Comment: Yes, can you give you Email adress or  whatsapp.

Comment: Try fixing your question, fill it with more detail like adding your code and showing how actually you tried.

Comment: `btndownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    recyclerViewClickInterface.onItemDownload(getAdapterPosition());

                }
            });`

**this is Button Click Listner **

Comment: `public interface RecyclerViewClickInterface {

    void onItemClickOnline(int position);

    void onItemClickOffline(int position);

    void onItemDownload(int position);
}
`

here is interfface and ftn

Comment: `Button btndownload = recyclerView.getChildAt(position).findViewById(R.id.downloadid);

        btndownload.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        DataHere.getHide().set(position, true);
        Save();`

Condition on button download function

Comment: `public void Save() {
        SharedPreferences preferences =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("comesting.example.codingstars6", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (boolean i : DataHere.getHide()) {
            builder.append(i ? '1' : '0');
        }

        editor.putString("BOOLEAN_ARRAY", builder.toString()).apply();
    }`
SAVE FUNCTION

Comment: `public void Load() {
        SharedPreferences preferences =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("comesting.example.codingstars6", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String arrayPrefs = preferences.getString("BOOLEAN_ARRAY",null);

        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(arrayPrefs)){
            DataHere.getHide().clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < suratE.size(); i++){
                assert arrayPrefs != null;
                DataHere.getHide().add(arrayPrefs.charAt(i) == '1');
            }
        }
    }`
LOad function

Comment: `public class DataHere {

    public static ArrayList<Boolean> hide = new ArrayList<>();

    public static ArrayList<Boolean> getHide() {
        return hide;
    }

    public static void setHide(ArrayList<Boolean> hide) {
        DataHere.hide = hide;
    }

}`